# How can i resize the text in MDDropdownMenu? (kivymd, python)

Tags: python, kivymd

I have a problem. I'm trying to change the size (or style) of the text inside the menu_items, I've already tried this approach:

```
 def open_menu(self, button):
            self.menu_items = [{'text': 'Example item {}'.format(i),
                                'font_style': 'H2'}
                               for i in range(15)]
            self.menu = MDDropdownMenu(caller=button, items=self.menu_items, width_mult=4)
            self.menu.open()
```

but without any result. Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone who has this problem:
You need to instantiate the font_style variable in the menu class you are using within the "menu.py" file, for example:

```
class MDMenuItem(MDMenuItemBase, OneLineListItem):
    font_style=StringProperty()
```

Then in the "create_menu_items" object of the "MDDropdownMenu" class look for the menu where you added the font_style variable and and initialize it, in my case:

```
item = MDMenuItem(
     text=data.get("text", ""),
     divider=data.get("divider", "Full"),
     font_style=data.get("font_style","Body1"),
     _txt_top_pad=data.get("top_pad", "20dp"),
     _txt_bot_pad=data.get("bot_pad", "20dp"),
)
```

Go back into your project and edit as I did in the question and it should work! :)